# Error: The license key is invalid. In order to use Plesk,

Tags: plesk

I am installing plesk 12.5 version and I am getting this error:

Error: The license key is invalid. In order to use Plesk, you need to obtain and install a new valid license key.
The license key is intended only for use with Plesk operating inside a VMWare virtual environment.

Has some one has a solution to this problem??

thanks
venkat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your Plesk is installed on a not supported virtualization environment.
You can find more detail here - http://kb.odin.com/en/122762

Comment: Right It was installed on openstack. Thanks